# @Rollback(true) not working in spring boot 1.3.X

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-test

I have updated my pom from spring-boot-starter-parent 1.2.5.RELEASE to 1.3.2.RELEASE.

The problem is that everything stay the same but all the test `@Rollback(true)` not working at all after migration.

```
   @Transactional
    @Rollback(true)
    @Test
    public void testRollBack() {
         dao.saveToDb();
         throw new RunTimeException();
    }
```

Configaturation:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}
```

It works perfectly in the same configuration and code and the only change is spring boot version. I cannot see that Transaction is being created in logs as suppose too

Anyone has a clue? Maybe a way to debug and understand what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Posted the code.. It is very weird, and i couldn't find anything on migration/release document on spring

Comment: I just verified that the _Spring TestContext Framework_ has **never** supported `@Primary` for transaction mangers. Thus, are you absolutely positive that you only changed the version of Spring Boot from 1.2.5 to 1.3.2?

Comment: What happens if you add `assertTrue("in transaction?", TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());` to your test method with Spring Boot 1.2.5 _and_ 1.3.2?

Comment: I the logs. I can try it later or send it to the Jira as attachment.. The logs are in debug level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put spring on debug..
There is a problem/bug in the test framework or i don't understand the use correctly.
I checked the code of spring and saw this:

```
bf.getBean(DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_NAME, PlatformTransactionManager.class);
```

This happens when we have several transaction manager, instead of getting the bean marked by `@Primary` annotation spring try to get transaction manager that called "transactionManager".

The solution is just mark the bean in that name.. Tried to open issue to spring-test project but don't know where.. If anyone knows how please advise.

Thanks

EDIT: So the solution is eiether what i have wrote above or just name them transaction(`@Transactional("myManager")`) and use it in the test method signature

Comment: Spring Test is part of Spring Framework. It uses JIRA for issue management: http://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR.

Comment: Yes but i don't have user for their Jira :)

Comment: You can create a new user here: https://jira.spring.io/secure/Signup!default.jspa

Comment: I have created a JIRA issue to track this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13891

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

`TransactionTestExecutionListener` has changed quite a lot between Spring Framework 4.1 (used by Spring Boot 1.2) and Spring Framework 4.2 (used by Spring Boot 1.3). It sounds like there's been a change in behaviour which I suspect probably wasn't intentional.

To fix your problem without renaming one of your beans, you need to tell the test framework which transaction manager to use. The easiest way to do that is via the `@Transactional` annotation:

```
@Transactional("txManager")
@Rollback(true)
@Test
public void testRollBack() {
     dao.saveToDb();
     throw new RunTimeException();
}
```

Comment: You are right, Thanks for the answer but i don't want to change the code. After checking spring code and logs i saw that if i call the primary bean as "transactionManager" it works ok. You can see my answer below

Comment: FYI: there is no change in behavior within Spring's testing support. See the discussions in [SPR-13891](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13891) for details.